# How to calculate number of days between two given dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

If I have two dates (ex. `'8/18/2008'` and `'9/26/2008'`), what is the best way to get the number of days between these two dates?

Answer (score 1200, accepted):

If you have two date objects, you can just subtract them, which computes a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2008, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```

The relevant section of the docs:
https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258465) for another example.

Comment: Great answers here. Since a lot of the folks might be using pandas data frame, thought might be useful to check the link on how to convert from `np.datetime64` to `python datetime` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982056/how-to-convert-numpy-datetime64-ns-to-python-datetime

Comment: The nice thing is that this solution also returns correct delta for leap years.

Comment: That's why i love python - things like this, which make an technical complex problem feel solved in a natural way

Comment: Does this account for leap seconds?

Comment: in case you need to exclude weekends and holidays (workdays) try this https://github.com/cadu-leite/networkdays - its simple and add no third dependencies

Comment: Note that the result is not inclusive, i.e., 2019/05/01 to 2019/05/03 counts as 2 days.

Answer (score 238):

Using the power of datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"

a = datetime.strptime('8/18/2008', date_format)
b = datetime.strptime('9/26/2008', date_format)

delta = b - a

print(delta.days) 

# that's it how to calculate number of days between two given dates
```

Comment: actually, the date class would be more appropriate in this case than datetime.

Comment: @JeremyCantrell And yet, even eight years later, `date` still lacks its own equivalent to `strptime()`.

Comment: Why needs `strptime` the `format` arg? Should be clear with the first arg date which has a format.

Answer (score 64):

Days until Christmas:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> someday = datetime.date(2008, 12, 25)
>>> diff = someday - today
>>> diff.days
86
```

More arithmetic [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20061007015511/http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet236.html).

Comment: Updated answer: -4602

Comment: Correction: 
 today = datetime.today()

Answer (score 26):

everyone has answered excellently using the date,
let me try to answer it using pandas

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2008/08/18', format='%Y/%m/%d')
dt1 = pd.to_datetime('2008/09/26', format='%Y/%m/%d')

(dt1-dt).days
```

This will give the answer.
In case one of the input is dataframe column. simply use **dt.days** in place of **days**

```
(dt1-dt).dt.days
```

Answer (score 23):

You want the datetime module.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime 
>>> datetime(2008,08,18) - datetime(2008,09,26) 
datetime.timedelta(4)
```

Another example:

```
>>> import datetime 
>>> today = datetime.date.today() 
>>> print(today)
2008-09-01 
>>> last_year = datetime.date(2007, 9, 1) 
>>> print(today - last_year)
366 days, 0:00:00
```

As pointed out [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/How-Compute-of-Days-between-Two-Dates-tp1711833p1711841.html)

Comment: How do I get this without the 0:00:00 part?

Comment: @VickiB `delta = today - last_year` 
`print(delta.days)`

Comment: Note the calculation order: from_earlier_time - to_later_time, then you get a positive timedelta! Not the other way. Kinda weird.

Answer (score 18):

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime.strptime('8/18/2008', "%m/%d/%Y")
end_date = datetime.strptime('9/26/2008', "%m/%d/%Y")
print abs((end_date-start_date).days)
```

Comment: This adds nothing new compared to the answers given 4 years earlier. -1.

Comment: +1 for the use of `abs()`, which is useful when the compared dates are unknown beforehand and it is the difference you are interested in. If your second date in `datetime.strptime(date, date)` is later than the first date, the result will be negative. `abs()` makes all input absolute (ie. positive).

Answer (score 12):

It also can be easily done with `arrow`:

```
import arrow

a = arrow.get('2017-05-09')
b = arrow.get('2017-05-11')

delta = (b-a)
print delta.days
```

For reference: http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 11):

without using Lib just pure code:

```
#Calculate the Days between Two Date

daysOfMonths = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def isLeapYear(year):

    # Pseudo code for this algorithm is found at
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm
    ## if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common Year)
    #else if (year is not divisable by 100) then (ut us a leap year)
    #else if (year is not disible by 400) then (it is a common year)
    #else(it is aleap year)
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0

def Count_Days(year1, month1, day1):
    if month1 ==2:
        if isLeapYear(year1):
            if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]+1:
                return year1, month1, day1+1
            else:
                if month1 ==12:
                    return year1+1,1,1
                else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1
        else: 
            if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]:
                return year1, month1, day1+1
            else:
                if month1 ==12:
                    return year1+1,1,1
                else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1
    else:
        if day1 < daysOfMonths[month1-1]:
             return year1, month1, day1+1
        else:
            if month1 ==12:
                return year1+1,1,1
            else:
                    return year1, month1 +1 , 1


def daysBetweenDates(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2,end_day):

    if y1 > y2:
        m1,m2 = m2,m1
        y1,y2 = y2,y1
        d1,d2 = d2,d1
    days=0
    while(not(m1==m2 and y1==y2 and d1==d2)):
        y1,m1,d1 = Count_Days(y1,m1,d1)
        days+=1
    if end_day:
        days+=1
    return days


# Test Case

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28,False), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1,False), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30,False), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8,False), 585 ),
                  ((1994,5,15,2019,8,31,False), 9239),
                  ((1999,3,24,2018,2,4,False), 6892),
                  ((1999,6,24,2018,8,4,False),6981),
                  ((1995,5,24,2018,12,15,False),8606),
                  ((1994,8,24,2019,12,15,True),9245),
                  ((2019,12,15,1994,8,24,True),9245),
                  ((2019,5,15,1994,10,24,True),8970),
                  ((1994,11,24,2019,8,15,True),9031)]

    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code. If you try daysBetweenDates(*(2013,2,28,2013,1,1,False)), it will end up in an infinite loop because the condition y1 > y2 in the daysBetweenDates is not very well thought-out. Moreover, in the Count_Days, you use if month1 ==2 on the first line, and then if month1 ==12 on the 5th line. This is redundant or perhaps even a mistake. The first if will not allow the following if to be True by design.

Answer (score 9):

For calculating dates and times, there are several options but I will write the simple way:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
import dateutil.relativedelta

# current time
date_and_time = datetime.now()
date_only = date.today()
time_only = datetime.now().time()

# calculate date and time
result = date_and_time - timedelta(hours=26, minutes=25, seconds=10)

# calculate dates: years (-/+)
result = date_only - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(years=10)

# months
result = date_only - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=10)

# week
results = date_only - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(weeks=1)

# days
result = date_only - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=10)

# calculate time 
result = date_and_time - timedelta(hours=26, minutes=25, seconds=10)
result.time()
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

There is also a `datetime.toordinal()` method that was not mentioned yet:

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.date(2008,9,26).toordinal() - datetime.date(2008,8,18).toordinal())  # 39
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal

> `date.`**toordinal()**
>
> Return the proleptic Gregorian ordinal of the date, where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1. For any `date` object *d*,
>   `date.fromordinal(d.toordinal()) == d`.

Seems well suited for calculating days difference, though not as readable as `timedelta.days`.

Comment: There are cases in which this approach wins. For example, the actual  difference between 2019-07-09 23:50 and 2019-07-10 00:10 is twenty minutes. `(d1 - d0).days` returns `0`, `d1.toordinal() - d0.toordinal()` returns `1`. Depends on what you need in your actual usecase.

Comment: this approach can actually compare datetime and date. 
For example to check if 2020-04-17 == 2020-04017 00:00:00

Answer (score 6):

```
from datetime import date
def d(s):
  [month, day, year] = map(int, s.split('/'))
  return date(year, month, day)
def days(start, end):
  return (d(end) - d(start)).days
print days('8/18/2008', '9/26/2008')
```

This assumes, of course, that you've already verified that your dates are in the format `r'\d+/\d+/\d+'`.

Comment: This adds nothing new compared to the answers given 8 years earlier. -1.

Comment: The main difference is most of the other answers didn't even bother to account for the fact that the OP had his dates as strings. And those who did account for that largely used more complicated formatters than strictly necessary. So, the main difference is `map(int, s.split('/'))`. Not exactly groundbreaking, but then again this question is pretty stupid basic. My answer just shows another way to skin the cat.

Comment: Also mentioned validating that dates are in the correct format, and gave a first-approximation validation regex. Which others didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three ways to go with this problem :

```
from datetime import datetime

Now = datetime.now()
StartDate = datetime.strptime(str(Now.year) +'-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
NumberOfDays = (Now - StartDate)

print(NumberOfDays.days)                     # Starts at 0
print(datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday)    # Starts at 1
print(Now.strftime('%j'))                    # Starts at 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using datetime object in python.

```
# A date has day 'd', month 'm' and year 'y' 
class Date:
    def __init__(self, d, m, y):
            self.d = d
            self.m = m
            self.y = y

# To store number of days in all months from 
# January to Dec. 
monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
                                            31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ]

# This function counts number of leap years 
# before the given date 
def countLeapYears(d):

    years = d.y

    # Check if the current year needs to be considered 
    # for the count of leap years or not 
    if (d.m <= 2) :
            years-= 1

    # An year is a leap year if it is a multiple of 4, 
    # multiple of 400 and not a multiple of 100. 
    return int(years / 4 - years / 100 + years / 400 )


# This function returns number of days between two 
# given dates 
def getDifference(dt1, dt2) :

    # COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF DAYS BEFORE FIRST DATE 'dt1' 

    # initialize count using years and day 
    n1 = dt1.y * 365 + dt1.d

    # Add days for months in given date 
    for i in range(0, dt1.m - 1) :
            n1 += monthDays[i]

    # Since every leap year is of 366 days, 
    # Add a day for every leap year 
    n1 += countLeapYears(dt1)

    # SIMILARLY, COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF DAYS BEFORE 'dt2' 

    n2 = dt2.y * 365 + dt2.d
    for i in range(0, dt2.m - 1) :
            n2 += monthDays[i]
    n2 += countLeapYears(dt2)

    # return difference between two counts 
    return (n2 - n1)


# Driver program 
dt1 = Date(31, 12, 2018 )
dt2 = Date(1, 1, 2019 )

print(getDifference(dt1, dt2), "days")
```

Comment: -1: Untested code. `dt = Date(01, 01, 2019 ) SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers.` Even if I fixed that error, IndexError was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code the calculation yourself, then here is a function that will return the ordinal for a given year, month and day:

```
def ordinal(year, month, day):
    return ((year-1)*365 + (year-1)//4 - (year-1)//100 + (year-1)//400
         + [ 0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334][month - 1]
         + day
         + int(((year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or year%400==0) and month > 2))
```

This function is compatible with the [`date.toordinal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) method in the datetime module.

You can get the number of days of difference between two dates as follows:

```
print(ordinal(2021, 5, 10) - ordinal(2001, 9, 11))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a date handling library (or you suspect it has bugs in it), here's an abstract algorithm that should be easily translatable into most languages.

Perform the following calculation on each date, and then simply subtract the two results. All quotients and remainders are positive integers.

Step A. Start by identifying the parts of the date as **Y** (year), **M** (month) and **D** (day). These are variables that will change as we go along.

Step B. Subtract 3 from M

> (so that January is -2 and December is 9).

Step C. If M is negative, add 12 to M and subtract 1 from the year Y.

> (This changes the "start of the year" to 1 March, with months numbered 0 (March) through 11 (February). The reason to do this is so that the "day number within a year" doesn't change between leap years and ordinary years, and so that the "short" month is at the end of the year, so there's no following month needing special treatment.)

Step D.
Divide M by 5 to get a quotient Q₁ and remainder R₁. **Add Q₁ × 153 to D.** Use R₁ in the next step.

> (There are 153 days in every 5 months starting from 1 March.)

Step E. Divide R₁ by 2 to get a quotient Q₂ and ignore the remainder. **Add R₁ × 31 - Q₂ to D.**

> (Within each group of 5 months, there are 61 days in every 2 months, and within that the first of each pair of months is 31 days. It's safe to ignore the fact that Feb is shorter than 30 days because at this point you only care about the day number of 1-Feb, not of 1-Mar the following year.)

Steps D & E combined - alternative method

Before the first use, set L=[0,31,61,92,122,153,184,214,245,275,306,337]

> (This is a tabulation of the cumulative number of days in the (adjusted) year before the first day of each month.)

**Add L[M] to D.**

Step F
Skip this step if you use Julian calendar dates rather than Gregorian calendar dates; the change-over varies between countries, but is taken as 3 Sep 1752 in most English-speaking countries, and 4 Oct 1582 in most of Europe.

> You can also skip this step if you're certain that you'll never have to deal with dates outside the range 1-Mar-1900 to 28-Feb-2100, but then you must make the same choice for all dates that you process.

Divide Y by 100 to get a quotient Q₃ and remainder R₃. Divide Q₃ by 4 to get another quotient Q₄ and ignore the remainder. **Add Q₄ + 36524 × Q₃ to D.**

**Assign R₃ to Y.**

Step G.
Divide the Y by 4 to get a quotient Q₅ and ignore the remainder. **Add Q₅ + 365 × Y to D.**

Step H. (Optional)
You can add a constant of your choosing to D, to force a particular date to have a particular day-number.

Do the steps A~G for each date, getting D₁ and D₂.

Step I.
Subtract D₁ from D₂ to get the number of days by which D₂ is after D₁.

Lastly, a comment: exercise extreme caution dealing with dates prior to about 1760, as there was not agreement on which month was the start of the year; many places counted 1 March as the new year.

Comment: This just gets a plus for interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a date object for every calendar day between a start and end point then this code may help.
It returns a date object for every day between start and end:

```
from math import ceil
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta


def day_range(start: datetime, end: datetime) -> date:
    first_day = start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    daycount = ceil((end - first_day) / timedelta(days=1))
    for n in range(daycount):
        yield (start + timedelta(days=n)).date()


start = datetime(2023, 1, 1, 23, 0)
end = datetime(2023, 1, 4, 0, 20)

for day in day_range(start, end):
    print(f"Day: {day}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).