# How to Calculate the number of days in the year(s) between 2 dates in python

Tags: python, datetime

For example:

```
date 1 : 1 january 2000  
date 2 : 17 november 2006
```

I want to know how many days there are between date 1 and date 2 in the year 2000, 2001, ..., 2006
so I need something that returns something like this (doesn't matter if it's in a list or something):
2000: 365, 2001: 365, ..., 2006: 320

I've looked for something like this on the internet but that only turned up ways to calculate the number of days/months/years between 2 dates

Comment: Do you need to include leap years as well? Or are you assuming all years have 365 days?

Comment: have a look at [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html) and the date/time section, great reference for this kinds of problems...

Comment: Yes leapyears have to be included as since the code will be used to calculate interests over a long time with varying interest levels over the years.

Comment: Have a look at the `dateutil` module, as well. (and more specifically, it's `relativedelta`s) It makes some of this considerably more convienent. http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: better than all of these answers, see the top answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-days-betwen-two-dates-using-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hm, try something like this:

```
import datetime, calendar
date1 = datetime.date(year1, month1, day1) # month and day are 1-base
date2 = datetime.date(year2, month2, day2)
days_in_first_year = (datetime.date(year1,12,31)-date1).days
days_in_last_year = (date2 - datetime.date(year2, 1, 1)).days
if year1 != year2:
    n_days_list = [days_in_first_year]
    for year in range(year1+1, year2): n_days_list.append(365 + (1*calendar.isleap(year)))
    n_days_list.append(days_in_last_year)
else: n_days_list = [days_in_first_year + days_in_last_year]
```

haven't tested this, might be some off-by-one errors; make sure it does what you expect.

edit: correct the boundaries of the range() call, correctly handle year1 == year2

Comment: Great, works just fine, damn I have been trying to do something like this myself for about 3 days now - feels stupid - you just solved it in 1minute, Thankyou

Comment: Thanks! The first solution was wrong -- the range() call was, in fact, incorrectly slid a year to the left. I also updated it to handle year1==year2 correctly.

Comment: and the problem with the year1 == year2 is easy to solve btw but you'll probably know that yourself :p

Comment: there is still a bug in the script, the first year is missing a day because of the method you use to calculate the number of days in it, have to append 1 day there

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> start_date = datetime.datetime(2006, 7, 3)
>>> end_date = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 21)
>>> years = range(start_date.year, end_date.year + 1)
>>> start, end = start_date, end_date + datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> for year in years:
...     year_start = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0)
...     year_end = datetime.datetime(year + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
...     print(year, min(end, year_end) - max(start, year_start))
... 
2006 182 days, 0:00:00
2007 365 days, 0:00:00
2008 366 days, 0:00:00
2009 365 days, 0:00:00
2010 365 days, 0:00:00
2011 365 days, 0:00:00
2012 356 days, 0:00:00
```

UPDATE: You should probably add a `datetime.timedelta(1)` to the end date, because otherwise you'd be off with one day at the end. Fixed. But that depends on whether you want to include it or exclude it.

Answer (score 4):

```python
from datetime import date

DATE_END = date(2006, 11, 17)

def get_days(date_start):
    return (DATE_END - date_start).days

starting_dates = [
    date(2000, 1, 1),
    date(2001, 1, 1),
    date(2002, 1, 1),
]

print map(get_days, starting_dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this pseudocode to see if a year is a leap-year or not

```
if year modulo 400 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0
       then not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else
       not_leap_year
```

to create a list of all leap-years and the years that's not.

Comment: `from calendar import isleap`

Answer (score 0):

You can have something simply by doing this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")
>>> (datetime.now() - d1).days
3907
```

Comment: while this answers exactly what the question title asks for, this is not what the question is actually about. Luckily, this is exactly what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

two parts: build the date ranges as tuples with a start and end date, build a dictionary whose key is the year and the values are the days.  I don't need to account for leap year in the calculation because that is automatic in the range calculation

```
date_ranges=[]
def buildDateRanges(start_year,start_month,start_day, end_year,end_month,end_day):
     start_date=datetime.datetime(start_year,start_month,start_day)
     end_date=datetime.datetime(end_year,end_month,end_day)
     start_year=start_date.year
     end_year=end_date.year
     date_ranges=[]
     if start_year != end_year:
          for year in range(start_year,end_year+1):
              if year==start_year:
            
  date_ranges.append((start_date,datetime.datetime(start_date.year,12,31)))
             elif year==end_year:
                 date_ranges.append((datetime.datetime(start_year+1,1,1),end_date))
     else:
          date_ranges.append((start_date,end_date))
      return date_ranges

 date_ranges=buildDateRanges(2006, 7, 3,2012,12,21)

def years_days(days):
    years = days // 365
    days = days % 365
    return years, days

 results={}
 for i in range(len(date_ranges)):
     start_date=date_ranges[i][0]
     end_date=date_ranges[i][1]
     days=(end_date-start_date).days
     years,days=years_days(days)
     year=start_date.year
     print(years,days)
     while True:
         if year==end_date.year:
              results[year]=days    
         else:
              results[year]=365
         year+=1
         if year>end_date.year:
             break    
 print(results)
```

output:
{2006: 181, 2007: 365.0, 2008: 365.0, 2009: 365.0, 2010: 365.0, 2011: 365.0, 2012: 356.0}

Answer (score -1):

1. Convert both days into seconds since the epoch (ie. 1 Jan 1970 Midnight)
2. Subtract.
3. The do the division to convert seconds into days for the difference.

Comment: 1. I think with "both days" you mean both dates? Am I correct to presume that?

Comment: Yes days should have been a date!