# Calculate datetime difference in years, months, etc. in a new pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
Name    start        end
A       2000-01-10   1970-04-29
```

I want to add a new column providing the difference between the `start` and `end` column in years, months, days.

So the result should look like:

```
Name    start        end          diff
A       2000-01-10   1970-04-29   29y9m etc.
```

the diff column may also be a `datetime` object or a `timedelta` object, but the key point for me is, that I can easily get the *Year* and *Month* out of it.

What I tried until now is:

```
df['diff'] = df['end'] - df['start']
```

This results in the new column containing `10848 days`. However, I do not know how to convert the days to *29y9m etc.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a simple function you can reach your goal.

The function calculates the years difference and the months difference with a simple calculation.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def parse_date(td):
    resYear = float(td.days)/364.0                   # get the number of years including the the numbers after the dot
    resMonth = int((resYear - int(resYear))*364/30)  # get the number of months, by multiply the number after the dot by 364 and divide by 30.
    resYear = int(resYear)
    return str(resYear) + "Y" + str(resMonth) + "m"

df = pd.DataFrame([("2000-01-10", "1970-04-29")], columns=["start", "end"])
df["delta"] = [parse_date(datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')) for start, end in zip(df["start"], df["end"])]
print df

        start         end  delta
0  2000-01-10  1970-04-29  29Y9m
```

Answer (score 30):

You can try by creating a new column with years in this way:

```
df['diff_year'] = df['diff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

Comment: In 2024, due to pandas version up('2.1.1'), this answer may raise an error 'ValueError: Unit Y is not supported. Only unambiguous timedelta values durations are supported. Allowed units are 'W', 'D', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns''

Comment: try `df['diff'].apply(lambda x: x.days/365.25)` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Pretty much straightforward with `relativedelta`:

```
from dateutil import relativedelta

>>          end      start
>> 0 1970-04-29 2000-01-10

for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'diff'] = relativedelta.relativedelta(df.ix[i, 'start'], df.ix[i, 'end'])

>>          end      start                                           diff
>> 0 1970-04-29 2000-01-10  relativedelta(years=+29, months=+8, days=+12)
```

Answer (score 13):

A much simpler way is to use date_range function and calculate length of the same

```
startdt=pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')
enddt = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
len(pd.date_range(start=startdt,end=enddt,freq='M'))
```

Comment: This is really simple solution if you already working with pandas in the project.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the most 'pandas' way to do it, without using any for loops or defining external functions:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A'], 'start': [datetime(2000, 1, 10)], 'end': [datetime(1970, 4, 29)]})
>>> df['diff'] = map(lambda td: datetime(1, 1, 1) + td, list(df['start'] - df['end']))
>>> df['diff'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda d: '{0}y{1}m'.format(d.year - 1, d.month - 1))
>>> df
  Name        end      start   diff
0    A 1970-04-29 2000-01-10  29y8m
```

Had to use map instead of apply because of pandas' timedelda64, which doesn't allow a simple addition to a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function to calculate the difference -

```
def yearmonthdiff(row):
    s = row['start']
    e = row['end']
    y = s.year - e.year
    m = s.month - e.month
    d = s.day - e.day
    if m < 0:
        y = y - 1
        m = m + 12
    if m == 0:
        if d < 0:
            m = m -1
        elif d == 0:
            s1 = s.hour*3600 + s.minute*60 + s.second
            s2 = e.hour*3600 + e.minut*60 + e.second
            if s1 < s2:
                m = m - 1
    return '{}y{}m'.format(y,m)
```

Where row is the dataframe `row` . I am assuming your `start` and `end` columns are `datetime` objects. Then you can use `DataFrame.apply()` function to apply it to each row.

```
df

Out[92]:
                       start                        end
0 2000-01-10 00:00:00.000000 1970-04-29 00:00:00.000000
1 2015-07-18 17:54:59.070381 2014-01-11 17:55:10.053381

df['diff'] = df.apply(yearmonthdiff, axis=1)

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
                       start                        end   diff
0 2000-01-10 00:00:00.000000 1970-04-29 00:00:00.000000  29y9m
1 2015-07-18 17:54:59.070381 2014-01-11 17:55:10.053381   1y6m
```

Comment: `"I cannot think of any direct functions that give the difference in years and months"`  See `relativedelta` in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @DeepSpace's answer, here's a SAS-like implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import relativedelta

def intck_month( start, end ):
    rd = relativedelta.relativedelta( pd.to_datetime( end ), pd.to_datetime( start ) )
    return rd.years, rd.months
```

Usage:

```
>> years, months = intck_month('1960-01-01', '1970-03-01')
>> print(years)
10
>> print(months)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What you are essentially doing is subtracting the dates, then you  get the days, convert the days into a string and split by " " and from the resulting list, the number of days is 1st item in the list. convert that to integer and divide by 365.

```
ad['yrs']=(ad.last_dt-ad.dt).apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[0]).apply(lambda x: int(x)/365)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total number of seconds and calculate the rest:

```
diff = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01') - pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')

diff.total_seconds() / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60) # years
# 2.0

diff.total_seconds() / (30 * 24 * 60 * 60) # months
# 24.333333333333332

diff.total_seconds() / (24 * 60 * 60) # days
# 730.0
```

For Pandas `Series` use the `dt` accessor: `df['diff'].dt.total_seconds()`.