# In python converting Datetime value to Number like excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion, python-datetime

In excel if we convert datetime i.e. (10/21/2023 2:00:49 PM) into number we get (45220.583900463)

using Udemy i am learning Python so i have started a project for myself i even use GPT too if i am stuck so below is code which i have written but i want to coonvert my df1_data["Call start Timestamp"] so that later i can concatenate it

## **code in Main.py:**

```
from Repeat215 import REPEAT
Repeat = REPEAT()
Repeat.repeat_processing()
```

## **code in Repeat215.py:**

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pdimport os

class REPEAT:
    def init(self):
        self.raw_Dir = "C:/Users/Kunal.Khaire/Desktop/My Python Projects/Report_Automation/Reports/215 Repeat/Raw"
        self.raw1 = None
        self.raw2 = None
        self.working1 = "C:/Users/Kunal.Khaire/Desktop/My Python Projects/Report_Automation/Reports/215 Repeat/Repeat Working 1.xlsb"
        self.working2 = "C:/Users/Kunal.Khaire/Desktop/My Python Projects/Report_Automation/Reports/215 Repeat/Repeat Working 2.xlsb"
        self.mtd = "C:/Users/Kunal.Khaire/Desktop/My Python Projects/Report_Automation/Reports/215 Repeat/Repeat Report MTD.xlsb"

    def get_raw_files(self):
        """This function get the last two file in directory"""

        full_paths = [os.path.join(self.raw_Dir, file) for file in os.listdir(self.raw_Dir)]
        sorted_files = sorted(full_paths, key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)
        latest_two_files = sorted_files[:2]
        self.raw1 = latest_two_files[1].replace("\\", "/")
        self.raw2 = latest_two_files[0].replace("\\", "/")

    def repeat_processing(self):
        """This function open 'Working1' file do the processing then
        open 'Working2' file and do the processing and finally open
        final 'MTD' file gets updated and saved"""

        wb_W1 = xw.books.open(self.working1)
        sheet = wb_W1.sheets("Previous Day")
        df1 = pd.read_csv(self.raw1, encoding="utf-16", sep="\t")
        if len(df1.iloc[-1, 0]) <= 20:
            df1_data = df1.iloc[1:]
            df1_data = df1_data.sort_values(by=["Mobile_Number", "Call start Timestamp"], ascending=[True, True])
            df1_data.insert(0, "Combined", df1_data["Mobile_Number"].astype(str) + df1_data["Agent BPID"].astype(str) + df1_data["Call start Timestamp"].astype(str))
            df1_data.insert(1, "Flag", df1_data["Combined"].astype(float).diff().fillna(0))
            sheet["C2"].value = df1_data.values
            wb_W1.save()
        else:
            df1 = df1.iloc[:-1]
            df1_data = df1.iloc[1:]
            df1_data = df1_data.sort_values(by=["Mobile_Number", "Call start Timestamp"], ascending=[True, True])
            df1_data.insert(0, "Combined", df1_data["Mobile_Number"].astype(str) + df1_data["Agent BPID"].astype(str) + df1_data["Call start Timestamp"].astype(str))
            df1_data.insert(1, "Flag", df1_data["Combined"].astype(float).diff().fillna(0))
            sheet["C2"].value = df1_data.values
            wb_W1.save()
```

I Tried searching in GPT but nothing is working tried to_datetime() then .timestamp() still not worked
i am sorry for such dumb question but please help me!!

my small testing:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

a = "10/21/2023 2:00:49 PM"
b = pd.to_datetime(a)
timestamp = b.timestamp()
print("1234" + str(timestamp))
```

output: 12341697896849.0 instead of 123445220.583900463

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)

Comment: well i read that what i grasp is they did reverse thing in want datetime to number they did number to datetime

Comment: for vanilla Python (no pandas), this has been answered in [How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9574793/10197418).

Answer (score 2):

The link I gave in my comment doesn't provide a complete answer (only the origin for Excel date). Combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249675/13525512), you could find the Excel value as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.to_datetime("10/21/2023 2:00:49 PM")
orig = pd.to_datetime('1899-12-30')
print((dt-orig) / pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
```

Output:

```
45220.58390046296
```

Comment: For an entertaining story that touches on why the starting year was 1899, see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: @Tranbi Thank you so much your solution worked thank you again thank you