# Convert datetime (e.g. 2016-01-01, 2016-01-11) to integer days (e.g. 0, 11) in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, datetime-format

**Is it possible to convert a timestamp object in the format "2016-01-01" (year month day) into number of days from new years?**

I'm getting my timestamp object by `str(pandas.to_datetime('today')).split(" ")[0]`

I would put code that I used to get it started but I don't even know where to begin except by making a dictionary for how many days are in each month and then calculating it the long way.  Is there something built in that I can use for this?

Comment: The `datetime.strptime` method and the `timedelta` method would be useful to you

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-days-betwen-two-dates-using-python)

Comment: @cricket_007 - The second link is useful here, but the OP is starting with a `datetime` and then converting it with `str()` for some reason, so instead of converting that back to `datetime` they can just dispense with `str()` in the first place.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It wasn't clear what the types were, so I provided both, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import dateutil
st_date = '2016-11-01'
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(st_date).date()
tm_diff = dt - date(2016, 1, 1);
print tm_diff.days
```

Comment: The OP already had a `datetime` object. There's no need to install and import third-party modules for this.