# How to calculate diff between two dates in django

Tags: python, django

I want to calculate days difference between current date and  previous date.
i am trying this code

```
requiremntObj = CustomerLeads.objects.all()
a = datetime.datetime.now().date()

for i in requiremntObj:
    date1=i.posting_date
    diff = a-date1
    print diff
```

I got a error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'unicode'`

For current date i am getting datetime object and for date1 i am getting unicode.

```
posting_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: is `posting_date` a `CharField` or `DateTimeField`?

Comment: What does the `CustomerLeads` model look like? Is `posting_date` a proper [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)? If not: Fix your model!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have `DateTimeField` you can use:

```
delta = datetime.now().date() - posting_date
print delta.days
```

If it is string, then you have to convert:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
a = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now().date()), date_format)
b = datetime.strptime(str(posting_date), date_format)
delta = b - a
print delta.days
```

Here is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151211/4592608).

Comment: i am getting this error  
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Replace `datetime.datetime.now()` in the answer code with `datetime.now()`

Comment: Thanks it is working but a = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now().date()), date_format)

Answer (score 3):

This code for HTML in Django

```
<p> {{ to_date|timeuntil:from_date }} </p>
```

This code for server site in python

```
import datetime

from_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21)

to_date   = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 25)

result = to_date - from_date
print(result.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import these modules

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

created_on = user.datetime_created.date()
today = timezone.now().date()
diff = (today-created_on).days
```