# unsupported operand types in django

Tags: django, django-models

first date

```
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

second date

```
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    e = Checkin.objects.all().values()
    t = last value in 'e'
    co = d.time()
    ci = t.time()
```

I want difference between 'co' and 'ci'

Comment: Please show the actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate diff between two dates in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229963/how-to-calculate-diff-between-two-dates-in-django)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I jus posted the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably need to make both of your `datetime` objects time zone aware.

I have a local Page model that has a DateTimeField called `first_published_at`. Here's how I handle:

```
target_tz = datetime.tzinfo('utc')
now_dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=target_tz)
inst = m.Page.objects.get(pk=18)
model_dt = inst.first_published_at.replace(tzinfo=target_tz)

print(now_dt - model_dt) # 734 days, 12:46:53.059321
```

Or you could make both of them timezone naive:

```
target_tz = None
now_dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=target_tz)
inst = m.Page.objects.get(pk=18)
model_dt = inst.first_published_at.replace(tzinfo=target_tz)

print(now_dt - model_dt) # Same as above
```