# How I can calculate the duration between these two times '9:38 AM - 4 Mar 2015' and '10:06 AM - 26 Feb 2015' in Python

Tags: python-3.6

I have a json file where I have publistime as one entry and I want to find the difference between to time.
"pubTime": "9:38 AM - 4 Mar 2015"
"pubTime": "12:52 AM - 4 Mar 2015",
pubTime": "5:03 PM - 3 Mar 2015",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate number of days between two dates using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-python)

Comment: The format is different so I am facing problem in doing the calculation. I am little new to Python

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Got it:

from datetime import datetime

date_1 = datetime.strptime('10:06 AM - 26 Feb 2015', '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')

date_2 = datetime.strptime('9:38 AM - 4 Mar 2015', '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')

diff = date_2 - date_1

print(diff)