# Calculate years + months + days between 2 dates?

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 person's birth information, I want to do some analysis on them.
Like, the difference between their age, seconds, years+months+days.
I tried this:

```
from datetime import date
a = date(1991, 07, 20)
b = date(1999, 06, 06)
print((a-b).days)
-2878
```

this gives me `2878` days, but i want to calculate `years + months + days`
i tried to divide 2878/365, but i want the exact calculations
How can i approach this?

Expected Output:

```
7 years x months x days
```

Comment: Please this SO post, that should get your started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/151211/2186184

Comment: @kabanus sorry typos

Comment: There are no exact calculations, because "month" and "year" are inexact measures. Is 366 days a year, or a year and a day? Is 28 days a month, or three days short of that? If imprecise is good enough, just divide by what you think "month" and "year" should be, as you did. If you want "exact calculations", stick with days.

Comment: Just like we say when someone ask our birthday, like person a is `26 years 10 months 23 days`

Comment: @Darkstarone thanks I got this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **`datetime`** and **`dateutil`**:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

date1 = datetime(1991, 7, 20)
date2 = datetime(1999, 6, 6)

diff = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)

years = diff.years
months = diff.months
days = diff.days

print('{} years {} months {} days'.format(years, months, days))
# 7 years 10 months 17 days
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For **strict** differences, i.e. differences between years, months and days, you can use the attributes of `timedelta` objects.

```
from datetime import date

a = date(1991, 7, 20)
b = date(1999, 6, 6)

months = a.month - b.month
years = a.year - b.year
days = a.day - b.day

print('{0} years, {1} months, {2} days'.format(years, months, days))

-8 years, 1 months, 14 days
```

For **time-aware** differences, you can use 3rd party `dateutil` as per [@Austin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812971/9209546).

Comment: Thanks plus one, I got this

Comment: Aahh, this seems pretty good to me, here job is done without using `relativedelta`, Thanks :)

Comment: @TarunK, Just note, output is not the same as Austin's answer.. this takes strict difference between years.

Comment: Oops, if I calculate this in real world, I think Austin's answer is right? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @TarunK, Yes, please accept his answer as correct if you want "real world" differences :). Tried to explain this in my answer + comment too.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I wished to calculate difference in real world