# How to convert numpy datetime64 [ns] to python datetime?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to convert dates from pandas frame values in the separate function:

```
 def myfunc(lat, lon, when):
        ts = (when - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z','s')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
        date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
        print("Numpy date= ", when, " Python date= ", date)
        return float(90) - next_func(lat, lon, date)
```

Invokation this function:

```
new_df['new_column'] =  np.vectorize(my_func)(lat, lon, new_df['datetime(LT)'])
```

But it raise error:

```
ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('int64') and dtype('<M8[s]')
```

How to convert numpy datetime64 [ns] to python datetime?

Comment: Welcome to hell! Whoever gave birth to this concept deserves an enternity of flogging ;) .... Which pandas / numpy version are you using? The behaviour changes with different numpy versions for extra fun

Comment: `np.datetime64('1970-01-01','s').item()` returns `datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)`.  'ns' returns an integer, but 'us' and larger produces the `datetime`.

Comment: @ChristianSauer NumPy is 1.15.3 and Pandas is 0.23.4

Answer (score 11):

I wonder if you need all this conversion work.  With the right time units a `datetime64` can produce a `datetime` object directly.

I'm not sure about your `when` variable, but let's assume it comes from `pandas`, and is something like a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
In [56]: time = pandas.date_range('6/28/2013', periods=5, freq='5D')
In [57]: time
Out[57]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2013-06-28', '2013-07-03', '2013-07-08', '2013-07-13',
               '2013-07-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5D')
```

The equivalent numpy array

```
In [58]: time.values
Out[58]: 
array(['2013-06-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-07-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-07-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-07-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-07-18T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
In [59]: time.values.tolist()
Out[59]: 
[1372377600000000000,
 1372809600000000000,
 1373241600000000000,
 1373673600000000000,
 1374105600000000000]
```

With `[ns]` the result is a large integer, a 'timestamp' of some sort.  But if I convert the time units to something like seconds, or even microseconds (us):

```
In [60]: time.values.astype('datetime64[s]')
Out[60]: 
array(['2013-06-28T00:00:00', '2013-07-03T00:00:00',
       '2013-07-08T00:00:00', '2013-07-13T00:00:00',
       '2013-07-18T00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
In [61]: time.values.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
Out[61]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 18, 0, 0)]
```

the result is a list of `datetime` objects.

Comment: Spot on - thank you! Can you by any chance recommend a simple way to plot `time` in matplotlib - or is this the only way?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this workaround because sometimes np.datetime64 has different resolution

```
def ___convert_to_datetime(d):
    return datetime.strptime(np.datetime_as_string(d,unit='s'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

for timestamp

```
def ___convert_to_ts(d):
    return datetime.strptime(np.datetime_as_string(d,unit='s'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').timestamp()
```

for instance

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


def ___convert_to_datetime(d):
  return datetime.strptime(np.datetime_as_string(d,unit='s'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')



def ___convert_to_ts(d):
  return datetime.strptime(np.datetime_as_string(d,unit='s'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').timestamp()


print(___convert_to_datetime(np.datetime64('2005-02-25')))

my_ns_date = np.datetime64('2009') + np.timedelta64(20, 'ns')

print(my_ns_date)

print(___convert_to_datetime(my_ns_date))
```

output will be

> 2005-02-25 00:00:00
>
> 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000000020
>
> 2009-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 3):

```
def myfunc(lat, lon, when):
    ts = (when - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z','s')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
    print("Numpy date= ", when, " Python date= ", date)
    return float(90) - next_func(lat, lon, date)
```

try this code

to convert numpy datetime64[ns] to python datetime you just try the following code segment

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcfromtimestamp('your_time_stamp')
```

Comment: what's the output

Answer (score 0):

And if you simply want to query another date, you can just write the date as a string:

```
df[df['Date'] < '2011-08-01']
```