# Calculate number of days of periods in year using Django (queryset) - postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to figure out how to calculation a total number of period in a year in the database. Take for example, calculating total leaves in a year.

I am using:

```
Django - 1.11.7
Postgres - 9.4
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    leavedatefrom = models.DateField()
    leavedateto = models.DateField()
```

An Example to illustrate the issue:

```
leaves taken in 1 year (01/01/2019 - 31/12/2019)

record 1: (leavedatefrom)01/02/2019 - (leavedateto)05/02/2019 ===> 5 days
record 2: (leavedatefrom)10/05/2019 - (leavedateto)12/05/2019 ===> 3 days

Total days = 5 + 3 = 8 days
```

How can calculate in Django of the number of days of periods in the database in a year ? Basically I want to get 8 days in the example above.

Comment: Where do you want to save the result? Do you already have the records?

Comment: yes in the model - the fields: (leavedatefrom and leavedateto)

Comment: great. See my answer below - hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically make a query to get all the relevant leaves in the year by using the [`gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#gte) and [`lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#lte) django lookups.
For example:

```py
import datetime
leaves = Leave.objects.filter(
    leavedatefrom__gte=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
    leavedateto__lte=datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)
)
```

And then go over all the leaves and calculate the days delta between them and sum it up into another variable:

```
total_days = 0
for leave in leaves:
    total_days += (leave.leavedateto - leave.leavedatefrom).days
print total_days
```

See [How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) for more details and options on calculating the date ranges.

**EDIT:**
One optimization that can be made if you don't want to hit the DB each iteration is to use django [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
leaves = Leave.objects.filter(
    leavedatefrom__gte=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
    leavedateto__lte=datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)
).values_list('leavedatefrom', 'leavedateto')

total_days = 0
for leavedateto, leavedatefrom in leaves:
    total_days += (leavedateto - leavedatefrom).days
print total_days
```

Comment: It will hit the DB **`N`**  times during the iteration.

Comment: Thanks @JPG - It's also possible to use `values_list` in the query and go over the values instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm bit late. You could get the sum of days in a single SQL query

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField, ExpressionWrapper, Sum

Leave.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    diff_date_in_integer=ExpressionWrapper(F('leavedateto') - F('leavedatefrom'), output_field=IntegerField())
).annotate(
    diff_date_in_days=ExpressionWrapper(F('diff_date_in_integer') / (1000000 * 60 * 60 * 24), output_field=IntegerField())).aggregate(
    sum=Sum('diff_date_in_days'))
```

In the **`filter(...)`** clause, you can add the filtering conditions such as the `datetime` or the *`user specific data`*

---

#### Description

1. annotate the difference between **`leavedateto`** and **`leavedatefrom`** in ***"integer"*** format (in `diff_date_in_integer` annotated field )
2. Converted the **`diff_date_in_integer`** data to **`days`**
3. using **`aggregate()`** function and **`Sum()`** DB function, we findount the total days.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a naive approach to get the list of periods.

Fetch all the leave records from the system and for each record, find out the period of days.

```
leaves = Leave.objects.filter(leavedatefrom__gte=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), leavedateto__lte=datetime.date(2019, 12, 31

for leave in leaves:
    days = (leave.leavedatefrom.date() - leave. leavedateto.date()).days()
    period_list.append(days)
total_leaves = sum(period_list)
```