# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' when passing two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I am trying to pass two dates values that are stored as string to find the number of days within a date range

```
start = 2019-09-01
end = 2019-09-10
```

I am trying to pass the above two variable into the below expression and get the below error:

```
date = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days + 1)]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Update:

Had to modify the date columns to strings because of the error `raised unexpected: ValueError('unconverted data remains: T00:00:00')`

Comment: You get the error because you can't subtract `str`ings. To find the difference, `start` and `end` have to be dates too.

Comment: Going by what you've shown, you are declaring `start` and `end` as `int`, expecting them to work like `date`, and are getting an error that could only happen if they were `str`. Somewhere along the line, you've reassigned those two variables to point to `str` objects.

Comment: @Bob I converted date to string because of the error `raised unexpected: ValueError('unconverted data remains: T00:00:00')`

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I have edited my initial post on why I had to convert dates to str

Comment: Did you use `strptime()` to get the date object ? Or throught the `date` constructor ?

Comment: As written above, `start` is `2009` and `end` is `2000`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `start` and `end` objects are `str`ings, you can do the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = "2019-09-01"
end = "2019-09-10"

# Convert the str dates to actual date objects:
start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")

date = [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days + 1)]
print(date)
# [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 10, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to find number of days may be:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = '2019-09-01'
end = '2019-09-10'

start_date = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')

date_difference = end_date-start_date
# date_difference is timedelta object, you can access days as
print(date_difference.days)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `strptime()` method creates a `datetime` object from a given string, which can be used to convert you date strings to the datetime object and then, you can just subtract them to get the delta between them.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

```
from datetime import datetime

start = "2019-09-01"
end = "2019-09-10"

dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
d0 = datetime.strptime(start, dateformat)
d1 = datetime.strptime(end, dateformat)
delta = d1 - d0
print delta.days
```

[How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

Now `datetime.strptime(your_date, format)` takes two arguments:- first argument is your date string or your date and the second argument is format like as `datetime.strptime("2019-09-11","%Y-%m-%d")`

```
start = '2019-09-01'
end = '2019-09-10'
```

simply you can do this

```
start = datetime.strptime(start,"%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.strptime(end,"%Y-%m-%d")
total_days = start - end
print(total_days.day)
```