# Setting more than 52 weeks in Python from a date

Tags: python

Having some issues in being able to differentiate a different set of data based on dates as I'm using the `.datetime(Year,Month,Day).strftime` 
function in Python.

It seems that once it hits the 52 weeks in a year, it starts repeating it again for the next year from Week 0 which is obviously correct.

What I want to know is, is there a way of differentiating the 53rd week (the 1st week of the next year) using various functions or loops?

I'm trying to do this so that I can create a graph that extends to the present date using the weeks as the independent factor (x-axis) - currently it just extends from Week 0 to Week 52 but should realistically extend beyond that.

I've been trying to think of a logic to apply in a `for loop` but haven't really wrapped my head around any ideas. Any guidance would be highly appreciated as I'm fairly new to the coding scene.

Thanks!

Edit:

This is what I currently have...

```
for index, row in dt.iterrows():
Month = dt['Month']
Day = dt['Day']
Year = dt['Year']
date_list.append(datetime.datetime(Year[index], dt['Month'][index], dt['Day'][index]).strftime("%W"))

dt['Week'] = date_list
```

As my dataset goes through more than 1 years (approx 5 years currently), wouldn't I have to repeat that isocalendar code for Week 54, 55, 56 etc...

Comment: It's very unclear what it is you're trying to do. Can you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You could simply calculate the number of days since the first date (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) and then `number_of_days//7 +1` to get the week number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`date.isocalendar()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) function to go from a date to an ISO week number, or [`date.fromisocalendar()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar) (new in Python 3.8) to go the other way. I found these by just opening up the [documentation for the `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and searching for "week".

You could enumerate all the weeks in the year using these like this (again, you'll need Python 3.8 for the `fromisocalendar()` function):

```
has_week_53 = date.fromisocalendar(year, 52, 1) + timedelta(days=7) != date.fromisocalendar(year + 1, 1, 1)
week_count = 53 if has_week_53 else 52
for week in range(week_count):
    date_of_monday = date.fromisocalendar(year, week, 1)
    # use date_of_monday somehow
```

Edit: Here is a way of determining the week count if you cannot use Python 3.8. According to the [Wikipedia article on ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week), the last week has the property that it always contains 28 December. So this tells you the week count:

```
week_count = date(year, 12, 28).isocalendar()[1]
```