# Handle the calculation of two dates in two different months

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing this simple issue in the following code:

```
df['Diff'] = df['updated'] - df['created']
```

the date diff returns a negative number of days when condition meets (for example) the case below:

```
df['updated'] == "2020-04-01" and "df['created'] == "2020-03-21"
```

Is there a way (that I can probably miss as I am new at python) other than build a def to apply on a specific columns to return the correct number of days and not "-20" which is the basic result between *updated* and *created*?

Many thanks

Comment: I've forgotten to say Hi... so Hi there !

Comment: Hi, try reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this for difference:

```
df['updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['updated'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['diff'] = df['updated'] - df['created']
print(df)

     updated    created    diff
0 2020-04-01 2020-03-21 11 days
```