# How to Calculate days between two dates using Python?

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I want to calculate Number of days Between Two Dates using Python Django. Here is my code

In my Html,

```
<form method='post' action="something">
  <input type="date"  name="firstdate">
  <input type="date" " name="lastdate">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

i am sending this form data to view function,i am getting date overthere in `dd-mm-yy` formet. and if i print  overthere, i am getting firstdate and lastdate in below formet,

```
2020-01-01 
2020-02-01
```

i want to calculate number of days between these two dates.How to Do that? i will be thankfull if anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming d0 is 2020-01-01 and d1 is 2020-02-01,

```
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```