# How to calculate working days using python between to dates?

Tags: python

I did find this solution [click here to see article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664780/how-to-calculate-days-between-two-dates-using-python) but still not exactly what I was looking for. The solution calculates all the days between 2 dates, including weekends. So, is there a solution that excludes the weekends in the calculation?

Comment: maybe the calendar module could help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did is take that solution and expand it this way:

```
crtD = datetime.datetime.strptime(pd.loc[x,'createDate'], '%m/%d/%Y') # start date
tdyD = datetime.datetime.today() # end date
dayx = tdyD - crtD # number of days between start and end date. Includes weekends
wkds = dayx.days + 1 # eliminates time stamp and just leaves the number of days and adds 1 day
wkns = round(wkds/7,0) # divides the number of days by seven and rounds the result to the nearest integer
networkdays = int(wkds - wkns) - 1
print(networkdays)
```

I embedded these lines of code in a **for** loop. Hope this helps. If you have a solution to include Holidays, please post it here.