# How to get count of days when week starts from Monday till current date in Python

Tags: python

I want the number of days from Monday. Like on Thursday it should return 4.
Below is the code, its not giving relevant result

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now() 
dt.weekday()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the documentation isoweekday should do the trick

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now() 
dt.isoweekday()
```

returns 4 on Thursday

Comment: Thanks, @Anton van der Wel
It worked.

Comment: please accept the answer with the checkmark icon so the question is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Weekday returns day number in format Monday -> 0, Tuesday -> 1 etc. etc., if you want it to start from one, just add 1 to the result.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate it normally and add one to the answer:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print(dt.weekday()+1)
```

or use the standard (official) method:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now() 
dt.isoweekday()
```