# Take a date from input and see how many days that it is from today

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that takes a date inputted by the user in 'yyyy mm dd' format and see how many days that input is from today. I have no idea how to do this but if u can help that would be great.

```
    input("This is a function to find the difference between today and a date 
    you enter. Enter the date in this format: 'yyyy mm dd' ")
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
year = int(input('Enter a year'))  #input the needed year
month = int(input('Enter a month')) #input the needed month
day = int(input('Enter a day'))  #input the needed day
neededdate = datetime.date(year, month, day)
days_remaining = neededdate - today
print(days_remaining.days)
```

I edited to input date, month and year.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am trying to get the user to input any date that they want while the program is running and see how far that is from today.