# Generate a random number which change every 24 hours

Tags: python, random

Hi I make a app and want to know can we use `random` module to generate a random number which will change every 24 hours?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, the random module creates random numbers

Comment: That contradicts the actual purpose of the module a bit, don't you think? Look into `random.seed()` but the purpose is a bit strange.

Comment: Can any other module could be usefull?

Comment: What's the use case of this?

Comment: Yes other modules could be useful. There's a random number module in most languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can reseed `random` by using a count of days since a fixed date:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import random

d0 = datetime(2008, 8, 18)  # Pick an arbitrary date in the past
d1 = datetime.now()
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)

random.seed(delta.days)
print(random.randint(1,10))
```

This will mean that `print(random.randint(1,10))` will produce the same number anytime you run this today, but a likely different number tomorrow.

The `delta` section of this code was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151211) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Wrap it in a function using `yield`, and only update the yielded value if elapsed time has incremented.  That would give a user friendly interface.

Comment: @pjs: That sounds like an answer worthy of being posted.

Comment: I decided to post my suggestion as a separate answer after thinking about the potential impact of reseeding on distributional behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can make use `random` and `datetime` module.

Here is the sample code:

```py
import random, datetime

x = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y:%m:%d")
random.seed(x)
r_int = random.randint(1, 100)
print(r_int)
```

Output:

```py
73
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions based on reseeding the PRNG are effectively using the `seed` function as your random number generator rather than the PRNG state update algorithm.  Because of this, there are no guarantees regarding the distributional properties of the result, whereas a good PRNG yields a sequence of values which pass numerous statistical tests for uniformity and lack of serial correlation.

The following solution wraps things up as a generator using `yield`, but the value to be yielded is only updated after the requisite period of time has passed, regardless of how many calls are made to the generator. If your app is intended to run for a multi-day extended period and you care about the distributional characteristics, I'd suggest something like this:

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint # , seed
import time

def durable_randint(*, low = 1, high = 100, duration = timedelta(days = 1)):
    assert isinstance(duration, timedelta), 'duration must be a "timedelta"!'
    today = datetime.now()
    # seed(today.strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
    last = today - 2 * duration
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        if now - last > duration:
            x = randint(low, high)
            last = datetime.now()
        yield x

if "__main__" == __name__:
    # The following is overriding the default duration of one day.
    # It will run for 45 seconds (15 iterations of 3 seconds),
    # changing the value generated every 10 seconds.
    gen = durable_randint(duration = timedelta(seconds = 10)) # lazy generator
    for _ in range(15):
        print(gen.__next__())   # next iteration of the generator
        time.sleep(3)
```

Uncommenting the lines involving `seed` will yield consistent results across multiple independent runs if the resolution is one day.