# Calculate days in months between 2 dates (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with events and for each event there is a start date and end date, I need to get the amount of days each event had in different months.

For example:

```
Event 1 Start date: 1.1.2021 End date: 4.3.2021

January 2021: 31 days
February 2021: 28 days
March 2021: 4 days
```

Anyway to do this using pandas/python library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: @nikeros: the post you linked does not answer the question. He is trying to group the days between two dates by month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`, you could follow this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# YOUR INPUTS
start_date = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = dt.datetime(2020, 4, 4)

# All the days between start_date and end_date
days = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
# Retrieve first day for each of the month within the range
d = {x.strftime("%Y%m"):x for x in sorted(days, reverse=True)}
# Append end_date
d = [*sorted(d.values()), end_date]

for d1, d2 in zip(d[:-1], d[1:]):
    n_days = (d2 - d1).days + (d1.month == d2.month)
    print("{:15s}:{:d}".format(d1.strftime("%B %Y"), n_days))
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code below prints the days contained in each month between the dates `d0` and `d1`.

It prints the days between `d0` and end of `d0` months. It then prints the days in each of the following months until it reaches `d1` month. At that point, it just prints the day of the `d1` date.

In this case, `datetime` and `dateutil.relativedelta` are used to handle datetime objects and month increases.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

d0 = date(2008, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2009, 9, 26)

def days_in_month(month, year):
    if month == 12:
        return (date(year+1, 1, 1) - date(year, month, 1)).days
    return (date(year, month+1, 1) - date(year, month, 1)).days

def get_month_year_string(date):
    return date.strftime("%B %Y")

d = d0
while d.month < d1.month or d.year < d1.year:
    days_to_end_month = days_in_month(d.month, d.year)
    if d == d0:
        days_to_end_month -= d0.day
    print(f'{get_month_year_string(d)}: {days_to_end_month} days')
    d = d + relativedelta(months=+1)
print(f'{get_month_year_string(d1)}: {d1.day} days')

# Output:
# August 2008: 13 days
# September 2008: 30 days
# October 2008: 31 days
# November 2008: 30 days
# December 2008: 31 days
# January 2009: 31 days
# February 2009: 28 days
# March 2009: 31 days
# April 2009: 30 days
# May 2009: 31 days
# June 2009: 30 days
# July 2009: 31 days
# August 2009: 31 days
# September 2009: 26 days
```