# How to compare two dates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have 2 dates I want the no of days between the 2 dates how to retrieve that

```
expiry_date = details['expires']
today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

For example

```
28/11/2021
29/11/2021
no.of.days=1
```

Comment: [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) > click on the link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two `datetime` objects, you can subtract them to get a `timedelta`.

```
diff = (datetime.datetime.strptime("29/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y") - 
        datetime.datetime.strptime("28/11/2021", "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

You can then convert to days:

```
diff.total_seconds() / 86400.
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the answer yourself first, then ask if you can't find anything.

[How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Use this