# Add a key/value pair(With caculation) in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, google-sheets, gspread

I used `gspread` and `pandas` to convert my google sheet into a `list` of `dictionaries`. My google sheet is shown as the following `list`: (It's a very long list, so I only list a few lines)

```
mysheet=[{'StartDate': '2021-10-02', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': Mike},{'StartDate': '2021-11-02', 'ID': 15673, 'Receiver': Jane}, ... {'StartDate': '2021-10-10', 'ID': 34653, 'Receiver': Jack}]
```

I want to add a `key`/`value` pair to this list, and the value will use the values from the former cells with a function. For example, I want to calculate how many days from today，so my list will show as this:

```
mysheetnew=[{'StartDate': '2021-10-02', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': Mike, 'Days':66 },{'StartDate': '2021-10-03', 'ID': 15673, 'Receiver': Jane, 'Days':65}, ... {'StartDate': '2021-10-5', 'ID': 34653, 'Receiver': Jack, 'Days':63}]
```

Please help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) I'm assuming the other date in this case is "now"

Comment: Thank you so much!! The function is useful and I think I will use that, but I don't know how to add that function to my list. I'm new to python. Could you please advise on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
mysheetnew = []
for item in mysheet:
    temp = item.copy()
    temp["keyname"] = value
    mysheetnew.append(temp)
```

and instead of `values`, you can put `func(temp["date"])` or else.
Hope it helped.

Edit :
More precisely

```
import datetime

mysheetnew = []
for item in mysheet:
    temp = item.copy()
    timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(temp["StartDate"], "%Y-%m-%d")
    temp["Days"] = timediff.days
    mysheetnew.append(temp)
```

This makes use of the `datetime` module to manipulate dates and to have the difference between two dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I successfully added a new pair with your code! Could you please explain more about that function part with my example? I don't know how to define and add that function in.

Comment: @mary-ma i have edited the post with the more advanced answer